# HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway when seeding database

Tags: asp.net-core

I receive this error only when I call extension method SeedDatabase from Configure in Startup.cs. If I comment that line, everything is working well.
[image: error]

Here is the Configure method from Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.SeedDatabase(); // if comment this works!
    }
```

There is the IApplicationBuilder extension class with the SeedDatabase method.

```
 public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    private const string DefaultAdminEmail = "admin@gmail.com";
    private const string DefaultAdminPassword = "admin";
    private const string DefaultUserEmail = "user@gmail.com";
    private const string DefaultUserPassword = "user";

    private static readonly IdentityRole[] defaultRoles = new IdentityRole[]
    {
        new IdentityRole(RoleName.Admin),
        new IdentityRole(RoleName.Member),
    };

    public static async void SeedDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
            var roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            await SeedRoles(roleManager);

            await SeedUsers(userManager, roleManager);
        }
    }

    private static async Task SeedRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        foreach (var role in defaultRoles)
        {
            var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task SeedUsers(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        var adminUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(DefaultAdminEmail);
        var memberUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(DefaultUserEmail);

        if (adminUser == null)
        {
            adminUser = new User()
            {
                UserName = DefaultAdminEmail,
                Email = DefaultAdminEmail
            };

            await userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, DefaultAdminPassword);
        }

        if (memberUser == null)
        {
            memberUser = new User()
            {
                UserName = DefaultUserEmail,
                Email = DefaultUserEmail
            };

            await userManager.CreateAsync(memberUser, DefaultUserPassword);
        }

        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, RoleName.Admin);
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(memberUser, RoleName.Member);
    }
}
```

Comment: `SeedDatabase` is throwing an exception - most likely, it is due to a connection failure but it could be almost *anything* at this stage.

Comment: Try [ASP.NET Core Module stdout log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log), will you have detail error message? Try to change `void SeedDatabase` to `Task SeedDatabase`, and replace `app.SeedDatabase();` with `app.SeedDatabase().Wait();`. If you put breakpoint on `SeedDatabase` line to debug line by line, which line will throw exception?

Comment: @TaoZhou Thanks you very much for the tip with .Wait() and breakpoint, I found the problem, it's because I have required columns in User table that I don't provide.

Comment: Greate. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you havethe port 44311 opened  on firewall , it seems that it cannot reach database

also you have to debug and check the error

here is a link to see how u can debug 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: `TCP port 44311 (unknown service): LISTENING  
UDP port 44311 (unknown service): NOT LISTENING  
portqry.exe -n 127.0.0.1 -e 44311 -p BOTH exits with return code 0x00000001.`  

The provided link is about migration and i don't know how this is going to help me

Comment: use search field within page  in left side menu and type debug

and what do you mean both exist ? you have to check if the ports are listening 

if you have windows .. go to cmd and type netstat -a -b

if they are not listening then the issue is the port is blocked as i mention on my answer up

Comment: try to disable firewall and give a try again  just for testing purpose , if it works , enable firewall and allow the port in it through advanced windows firewall

Comment: Yes, port 44311 is open, portqry.exe is checking right that and I simply provided you the output. I get same result from the cmd: `TCP    0.0.0.0:44311          ASUS:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information`
Also if you didn't read the first post, but everything is okey when i comment the seed db method.

Comment: run the CMD as administrator first then check , is the status of the port now listening or not listening ?

Comment: am getting confused on first post you said ports NOT LISTENING

Comment: There are UDP and TCP ports. UDP is not listening, but TCP is listening. Also I already ran the CMD as administrator and have given you an output: `TCP 0.0.0.0:44311 ASUS:0 LISTENING Can not obtain ownership information`